# Tensorflow multi-variable logistic regression not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I am trying to create a program which will classify a point as either `1` or `0` using [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). I am trying to create an oval shape around the center of this plot, where the blue dots are:

Everything in the oval should be classified as `1`, every thing else should be `0`. In the graph above, the blue dots are `1`s and the red x's are `0`s.

However, every time I try to classify a point, it always choses `1`, even if it was a point I trained it with, saying it was `0`.

My question is simple: Why is the guess always `1`, and what am I doing wrong or should do differently to fix this problem? This is my first machine learning problem I have tried without a tutorial, so I really don't know much about this stuff.

I'd appreciate any help you can give, thanks!

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

training_in = numpy.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [-2, 0], [-1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1.5, 1],   [3, 3], [3, 0], [-3, 0], [0, -3], [-1, 3], [1, -2], [-2, -1.5]])
training_out = numpy.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

def transform_data(x):
    return [x[0], x[1], x[0]**2, x[1]**2, x[0]*x[1]]

new_training_in = numpy.apply_along_axis(transform_data, 1, training_in)

feature_count = new_training_in.shape[1]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, feature_count])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([feature_count, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

guess = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(tf.matmul(x, W) + b, y))

opti = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    for (item_x, item_y) in zip(new_training_in, training_out):
        sess.run(opti, feed_dict={ x: [item_x], y: [[item_y]]})

print(sess.run(W))
print(sess.run(b))

plt.plot(training_in[:6, 0], training_in[:6, 1], 'bo')
plt.plot(training_in[6:, 0], training_in[6:, 1], 'rx')

results = sess.run(guess, feed_dict={ x: new_training_in })

for i in range(training_in.shape[0]):
    xx = [training_in[i:,0]]
    yy = [training_in[i:,1]]
    res = results[i]

    # this always prints `[ 1.]`
    print(res)

    # uncomment these lines to see the guesses
    # if res[0] == 0:
    #     plt.plot(xx, yy, 'c+')
    # else:
    #     plt.plot(xx, yy, 'g+')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you use [softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits). In your concrete case, both `logits` and `labels` should have shape `[batch_size, number_of_labels=2]`.

Note that your tensors `logits=tf.matmul(x, W) + b` and `labels=y` have shape `[batch_size, 1]`, so Tensorflow is assuming that  `number_of_labels=1`. That's why your guess is always the same.

**A)** You could solve this problem by encoding `training_out` as a one-hot vector. I recommend using [`np.eye()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) to achieve that:

```
training_out = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
training_out = numpy.eye(2)[training_out]
```

Then, you will need to make the following changes:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([feature_count, 2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
...
for i in range(1000):
    for (item_x, item_y) in zip(new_training_in, training_out):
        sess.run(opti, feed_dict={x: [item_x], y: [item_y]})
...
results = sess.run(guess, feed_dict={x: new_training_in})[:,1]
```

**B)** Alternatively, you could use [sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits), which allows `labels` to have shape `[batch_size]`.  I've tweaked your code to make it work in this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

training_in = numpy.array(
    [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [-2, 0], [-1, -1], [-1, 1], [-1.5, 1], [3, 3], [3, 0], [-3, 0], [0, -3], [-1, 3], [1, -2],
     [-2, -1.5]])
training_out = numpy.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

def transform_data(x):
    return [x[0], x[1], x[0] ** 2, x[1] ** 2, x[0] * x[1]]

new_training_in = numpy.apply_along_axis(transform_data, 1, training_in)

feature_count = new_training_in.shape[1]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, feature_count])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([feature_count, 2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

guess = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(tf.matmul(x, W) + b, y))

opti = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    for (item_x, item_y) in zip(new_training_in, training_out):
        sess.run(opti, feed_dict={x: [item_x], y: [item_y]})

print(sess.run(W))
print(sess.run(b))

plt.plot(training_in[:6, 0], training_in[:6, 1], 'bo')
plt.plot(training_in[6:, 0], training_in[6:, 1], 'rx')

results = sess.run(guess, feed_dict={x: new_training_in})

for i in range(training_in.shape[0]):
    xx = [training_in[i:, 0]]
    yy = [training_in[i:, 1]]
    res = results[i]

    # this always prints `[ 1.]`
    print(res)

    # uncomment these lines to see the guesses
    if res[0] == 0:
        plt.plot(xx, yy, 'c+')
    else:
        plt.plot(xx, yy, 'g+')
plt.show()
```